# How to check if a FileField has been modified in the Admin of Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms, django-file-upload

I am trying to do a model with a file that shouldn't be modified. But the comment of the file can be.

Here is what I did, but we cannot modify the comment.
How can I test if a new file (using the browse button) as been sent and in this case only, create a new instance of the model ? If no upload of a new file, update the comment.

**admin.py**

```
class CGUAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ConditionsUtilisation

    def clean_file(self):
        if self.instance and self.instance.pk is not None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'You cannot modify the file. Thank you to create a new instance.'))
        # do something that validates your data
        return self.cleaned_data["file"]

class CGUAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CGUAdminForm

admin.site.register(ConditionsUtilisation, CGUAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
class ConditionsUtilisation(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(_(u'Date d\'upload'), editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField(_(u'Commentaire de modification'))
    file = models.FileField(_(u'CGU'), upload_to='subscription/cgu/', storage=CGUFileSystemStorage())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if 'file' in form.changed_data:
     """
     File is changed
     """
     raise forms.ValidationError("No, don't change the file because blah blah")
else:
     """
     File is not changed
     """
```